# Android - Issue stopping a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

In my application I start a thread that runs a couple audio services by pushing a button, then attempt to stop it by pushing a stop button. The audio portion stops fine, but I see in the debugging window that the thread is still running. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the thread that is started, goTime is initialized to null as a global variable:

```
goTime = new Thread(new Runnable() { 

        public void run() { 

    rec.startRecording();
    player.play();
    while(isRecording && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        if(goTime.isInterrupted()){
            return;
        }
        ix=0;
        while(ix<bufLeng){
        short[] bufferor = buffers[ix++ % buffers.length];
        lastRead = ix;
        rec.read(bufferor, 0, 
                    bufferor.length);
        buffers[ix]=bufferor;
        inter.onMarkerReached(rec);
        }
    }
    if(goTime.isInterrupted()){
        return;
    }
        }});
    goTime.start();
```

And here is the method called when the stop button is pressed:

```
    public void stop(View view){
    isRecording=false;
    System.out.println("stop called");
    rec.stop();
    player.stop();
    player.flush();
    player.release();
    goTime.interrupt();
    //isRecording=true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's stuck in that inner while loop? use some Log print lines

Comment: I looks like you're right, the program is not getting into either of the if statements, but it's definitely getting into the stop method. Am I correctly interrupting the thread in the stop method?

Comment: Just change *while(ix<bufLeng)* to *while(ix<bufLeng && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())*. or something like that

Comment: Are you expecting Thread.interrupt() to interrupt a blocking read() call?  interrupt() only interrupts certain things.

Comment: But if I call stop() on the AudioRecord object, wouldn't that stop the read(), and thus allow for an interrupt() call to go through?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the values of objects between threads are cached by the JVM(or in this case Dalvik)
try declaring your isRecording like so:

```
private volatile boolean isRecording;
```

The volatile keyword will ensure the values are not cached but always written directly

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that didn't seem to help it.

Comment: Ok, I found the cause, but I'm unclear why exactly it is causing it. My application has five tabs for different audio effects, and three of them do not have this problem. The working tabs initialize the 2D array buffers to have size [10][256], while the two tabs that do not work have a much larger initialization size for this buffer. I'm not sure exactly why this would cause the thread to not exit properly, but that's the only difference I can see.